# replaceDialog() where the dialog is defind using dialog.matches

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have integrated LUIS with my chatbot, and almost all of my dialogs are defined using dialog.matches().
The problem is that some dialogs need to be redirected to other dialogs, but `replaceDialog` or `beginDialog` doesnt seem to be working for dialogs which are defined using dialog.matches.
Example: consider following dialog

```
options.dialog.matches('startActivity', [
        function(session) {
})
```

how do i manually invoke it from some other dialog? `session.replaceDialog('startActivity')` throws an error.

```
Error: Dialog[*:startActivity] not found.
    at Session.replaceDialog (D:\insight\ms-bot\src\api\node_modules\botbuilder\
lib\Session.js:146:19)
    at Array.options.dialog.matches.regEx (D:\insight\ms-bot\src\api\dialogs\mor
tgage\mortgage-check-account-balance.dialog.js:7:26)
    at Object.waterfallAction [as mortgageCheckBalance] (D:\insight\ms-bot\src\a
pi\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\DialogAction.js:130:25)
    at IntentDialog.invokeIntent (D:\insight\ms-bot\src\api\node_modules\botbuil
der\lib\dialogs\IntentDialog.js:264:44)
```

Refer [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1178) on githib

Answer (score 1):

The string you pass into matches() is the Intent to match not a dialog name. You need to break your waterfall out as a separate dialog so:

```
options.dialog.matches('startActivity', [
     function (session) {
           session.beginDialog('/startActivity');
     }
]);

bot.dialog('/startActivity', [
     function (session) { },
     function (session, results) {
          session.replaceDialog('/startActivity');
     }
]);
```